# JQuery ui toggle and hide the rest of the posts

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a list of posts. I'm only showing the minimal information on the posts but the user can toggle the post to show or hide. What I have right now is

```
$(".post").click(function(e){
    $('.post-additional-info').slideUp();
    $(this).children(".post-additional-info").slideToggle();
});
```

but the problem I'm having is that I can no longer hide with the toggle.

Comment: Posting a link to live site has no value for future users after the issue is updated or if the live site link changes. Post all relevant code needed to replicate problem in the body of your question

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want to `slideUp()` the current post child use `not()` to exclude it:

```
$(".post").click(function(e){
    var $currentChild = $(this).children(".post-additional-info");
    $('post-additional-info').not($currentChild).slideUp();
    $currentChild.slideToggle();
});
```